# JMenuItem doesn't execute action

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I've looked through the swing tutorials and i do not see what i'm doing wrong. Why is nothing happening when i click on the jmenuitem?

my first class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class WordProcess{

/*TODO: make program end on close
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame("Word Processor", 10000, 10000);
    }
}
```

second class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();


public MainFrame(String name, int x, int y) {
    setTitle(name);
    setSize(x, y);
    setVisible(true);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);



    //creates file menu and adds to menubar
    //TODO populate with JMenuItems 
    JMenu filemenu = new JMenu("file");
    filemenu.setVisible(true);
    menubar.add(filemenu);

    buttonnew buttonnew = new buttonnew("new");
    buttonnew.setVisible(true);
    filemenu.add(buttonnew);
}
}
```

and third class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class buttonnew extends JMenuItem implements ActionListener{

buttonnew(String s) {
super();
super.setText(s);
addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    JFrame newframe = new JFrame("sup");
}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I suggest you take the time have a read through the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) API as well

Answer (score 3):

When the button is pressed, it will create an empty, invisible `JFrame`. You won't see it, since you have not called `setVisible()` on it, and it's tiny, as it has no contents. Otherwise, the code is fine.

Comment: @user2465510, I would suggest you start accepting answers when you get help if you want to continue to get help in the future.